# Calc 2: Use integral test to determine if series converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm confused on how the series from $n$ to infinity of $n^2/e^{n/3}$ is considered decreasing.

After I took the first derivative I got $x(6-x)/3e^{x/3}$. Isn't the value supposed to be negative in order to be considered decreasing?

Thank you!

Comment: Is that not negative and hence decreasing for $x\gt6$?

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$$f(x):=\frac{x^2}{e^{x/3}}\implies f'(x)=\frac{e^{x/3}\left(2x-\frac{x^2}3\right)}{e^{2x/3}}=\frac{6x-x^2}{3e^{x/3}}\le0\iff x(6-x)\le0\iff$$

$$x(x-6)\ge0\iff x\le0\;\;\text{or}\;\;x\ge6\;\;$$

and from here that the sequence $\;\cfrac{n^2}{e^{n/3}}\;$ is monotonic decreasing for $\;n\ge7\;$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use monotone convergence theorem to prove this sequence converges, you can ignore finite terms (to make the series increasing/decreasing).
The reason is :
$a_{n}$ bounded $\Rightarrow$ $a_{n+N}$ bounded $\Rightarrow$ $a_{n+N}$ converge $\Rightarrow$ $a_{n}$ converge
It should be noted that $a_{n}$  does not converge to its supremum or infimum but converge to the supremum or infimum of $a_{n+N}$.